# Git: compare local branch to remote staging and production

Tags: git, github

I'm having trouble comparing local master (which is on same commit as origin/master) with production/master.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:mydomain/mydomain.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:mydomain/mydomain.git (push)
production  git@heroku.com:mydomain-production.git (fetch)
production  git@heroku.com:mydomain-production.git (push)
staging git@heroku.com:mydomain-staging.git (fetch)
staging git@heroku.com:mydomain-staging.git (push)
```

I seem to be able to get a diff with `staging/master` but I get errors with `production/master`:

```
$ git diff staging/master
[i'm shown diff]
$ git diff production/master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'production/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Anyone see what I'm screwing up?

What I really want to do is see the commits on local master that aren't on those to other remotes with something like `git diff production/master...master` but that gives same error:

```
$ git diff production/master...master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'production/master...master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: What I've used in the past is `git fetch production master && git diff master production/master`. Does that work for you?

Comment: that worked. I guess I'd never `git fetch`ed from that remote before?!? not sure exactly.

Comment: Awesome! I'll add it as an answer, then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I've used in the past is

```
git fetch production master && git diff master production/master
```

You might have never fetched from that remote before.

---

In terms of seeing the commits that aren't on `production/master` but are on local `master`, `git log` might be a better fit:

```
git log --oneline production/master..master
```